# How to put more chars in a line with nine-patch?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm using this nine-patch bg image.

[image]

How can I set its width to be wider (but not absolute)?

Is there any way to push exactly the same words in a line

when shown in different devices?

I want:
[image]

I have:
[image]

Comment: Just make the content area bigger in your 9-patch ? Change police size ?

Comment: you mean RIGHT borders? or how?

Comment: Right and bottom i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Write the text in a textView with background set as the 9 patch image
- Set the width of the textView as wrapcontent
- In case you store the text in string.xml give \n wherever you want new line